# RDD mapping to create hierarchy tree

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I construct a table/rdd such that it describes the level from parent . Given below are nodes and their corresponding child nodes after ":"

```
1: 3,4
2: 1,3
3: 6
4: 5
5:
6: 5
```

For the above table, if I have source input as 2 and destination as 5, how can iIconstruct an rdd such that it looks like

```
2 : null 0
1: 2 1
3: 2 1
4: 1 2
3: 1 2
6: 3 2
5: 4 3
```

Where the number next to : indicates the parent and the next digit indicates the levels to root node.

Comment: This is not a tree, but a directed graph. For instance, Node 3 has both nodes 1 and 2 as direct parents.

Comment: Being a graph you might want to try Sparks's GraphX, particular, [this seems to be very close (or identical) to what you want](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components)